# Parsing SQLite output

Tags: shell-script, scripting, sqlite

Using -line Option I get this output from SQLite:

```
row1_column1 = valueA
row1_column2 = valueB

row2_column1 = valueC
row2_column2 = valueD
```

So one line for each column value and result rows are separated by a blank line. I need to get this output in a array or list containing

```
valueA,valueB
valueC,valueD
```

Additionally non-numeric (!) values shall be enclosed by ' and '. 
Any simple way to do this? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you simply want to enable CSV output from SQLite:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE mytable ( field1 text, field2 integer );
```

```
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable;
┌───────────┬────────┐
│  field1   │ field2 │
├───────────┼────────┤
│ some text │ 1      │
│ more text │ 2      │
└───────────┴────────┘
```

```
sqlite> .mode line
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable;
field1 = some text
field2 = 1

field1 = more text
field2 = 2
```

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable;
"some text",1
"more text",2
```

From the command line:

```bash
$ sqlite3 mydatabase.db '.mode csv' 'SELECT * FROM mytable'
"some text",1
"more text",2
```

CSV output mode can also be set with the `-csv` command line option to the `sqlite3` command.

Answer (score 4):

The following awk script does what you want, and even escapes quotes in strings:

```
BEGIN   { RS="\n\n"
          FS="\n"
        }

function field(s)
{
        sub(/^[^=]*= /, "", s)
        if (match(s, /^[-][0-9]+$/) == 0) {
                gsub(/'/, "''", s)
                s = "'" s "'"
        }
        return s
}

        { print field($1) "," field($2) }
```

(The numeric regular expression does not handle floating-point values.)

---

But the simplest way to do this does not use `-line` but SQLite's built-in SQL quoting:

```
sqlite3 -separator , -list my.db 'select quote(col1),quote(col2) from mytab;'
```

Comment: the quote function is exactly what i was looking for, i had found the list option, but didn't know there is an sql statement for quoting. thank you very much!